# checkbox value checked if its value equals to 1

Tags: jquery

I want to make checkbox checked if its value == 1 and unchecked if value == 0. please suggest some logic. Thanks in advance who helping me.

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="preference" value="1" data-value="size1" id="datasize1">A</label>\
</div>\
<div class="checkbox">\
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="preference" value="0" data-value="size2" id="datasize2">B</label>\
</div>\
<div class="checkbox">\
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="preference" value="1" data-value="size3" id="datasize3">C</label>\
</div>\
<div class="checkbox">\
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="preference" value="1" data-value="size4" id="datasize4">D</label>\
</div>\
<div class="checkbox">\
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="preference" value="0" data-value="size5" id="datasize5">E</label>\
</div>\
<div class="checkbox">\
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="preference" value="1" data-value="size6" id="datasize6">F</label>\
</div>\
<div class="checkbox">\
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="preference" value="0" data-value="size7" id="datasize7">G</label>\
</div>

$('.preference').each(function(e){
    if($(this).val() == 1){
        $(this).checked;
    }
});
```

Comment: sir i want checkbox value checked on load. i don't want this on change or on click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close, but `checked` attribute is for JS object, not Jquery. For JQuery you set it's attribute "checked" to checked:

```
$('.preference').each(function(e){
    if($(this).val() == 1){
        $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
    }
});
```

Here is a **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ls8wgz5c/18/)**

Comment: thanks a lot man. Really appreciate for your kindness and helpful nature

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function

```js
function isCheckedById(id) {
  alert(id);
  var checked = $("input[@id=" + id + "]:checked").length;
  alert(checked);

  if (checked == 1) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```